# Problema ao executar SELECT em uma tabela no phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tenho várias tabelas em meu banco de dados, e até pouco tempo atrás, não havia nenhum problema em nenhuma delas. Eu conseguia administrar tranquilamente todo o banco pelo PHPMyAdmin. Porém, de repente, em uma das tabelas a query `SELECT *` parou de executar de forma adequada no PHPMyAdmin.

Ao executar a query `SELECT *` FROM Pontuação (ou simplesmente clicar sobre a tabela na interface), o PHPMyAdmin acusa um erro no servidor, e não dá mais nenhum detalhe. A query retorna os registros, mas mostrando apenas o conteúdo das três primeiras colunas da tabela (a tabela possui 14 colunas).

Vale ressaltar que esse é um problema exclusivo do PHPMyAdmin. A query `SELECT` na tabela Pontuação funciona normalmente no terminal do Linux e no MySQL Workbench.

Outro detalhe importante é que essa tabela é a que possui o maior número de registros no meu banco de dados. São quase 200.000 registros.

Alguém já teve problema parecido? Isso seria alguma restrição do PHPMyAdmin para tabelas com uma quantidade grande de registro? Tem algo que eu possa fazer para contornar o problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você poderia fornecer print do que está acontecendo? Poderia colocar seu código também?

Answer (score -1):

"... mas mostrando apenas o conteúdo das três primeiras colunas da tabela ...", Pode ser um problema com a codificação do phpmyadmin, tente usar o comando "SELECT * FROM Pontuacao" no terminal e verifique se há "ç", alguma pontuação ou qualquer carácter que especial.

Comment: Não há strings com caracteres especiais nessa tabela. Apenas datas, inteiros e strings criptografadas com sha-512 (ou seja, sem caracteres especiais). Descobri que executar um SELECT com mais de três colunas, o phpmyadmin só me retorna os valores das três primeiras colunas na query. Por exemplo, se eu executo a query "SELECT `idCliente`,`numEstabelecimento`,`numLoja`,`timestampPontuacao` FROM `Pontuacao`", o phpmyadmin me retorna apenas os valores das colunas idCliente, numEstabelecimento e numLoja.